# Why can't my compiler find my library?

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries

I'm trying to compile a simple C program using gcc:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "lbryTest.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double x = 0.0;
    x = lbryTest(2.0, 5.0);
    printf("%f", x);
    printf("Placeholder");
    return 0;
}
```

`lbryTest()` is a function that does some simple math operations and returns a `double`. It is declared in `lbryTest.h`, and defined in `liblbryTest.a`.

When I compile the code using

> gcc libraryTest.c -l lbryTest

I get the error:

> cannot find -llbryTest.

How can I fix this?

---

Thanks to John Bollinger's comment, it finds the library. I added `-L.` to the command. This doesn't however answer why it was unable to find the library in the first place. The files are all in the same directory. How can I make it so the library will be found without explicitly adding the path? Or is that unconventional in C, and you should always explicitly add the path to all libraries linked?

Comment: Is it in the same location as your main program?

Comment: Yes, they are all in the same folder.

Comment: Add an option `-L.` to the compilation command, *before* `-llbryTest`.

Comment: If everything is in the same folder, did you try -l ./lbryTest ?

Comment: I don't recall.  Should that space follow the `-l`?

Comment: Not necessarily. If your library is not in one of the 'known' locations to ld.so, then you either need to add it to the system and do a ldconfig, or try to give a path to it in the gcc command line.

Comment: The space between `-l` and its argument is unconventional, but probably ok for `gcc`.

Comment: I've tried it with the space and without, as well as -l./lbryTest and I got the same error. -L -llbryTest gave me error: lbryTest: No such file or directory.

Comment: The `-L` option takes a path.  So provide the path to wherever the library resides.  The error you see is because you have `-L -llbryTest` with no argument to the `-L`.

Comment: Ok I see, I missed the `.` after `-L`. Now it says my liblbryTest,a file is in the wrong format. Progress!

Comment: Library files `*.a` are not shared objects. They are archive libraries. You need to compile against them as static libraries. I believe `-static` should suffice.

Comment: Of importance is the actual naming of the library.   gcc wants the library to be named `lib---.so` or for static linking `lib---.a where the '---' is the part of the library name that goes after the -l parameter to the linker.

Comment: the `libname.a` is for when the 'static' parameter is passed to gcc.  For dynamically loaded libraries use `libname.so`   The library has to be properly created for the two different names as the internals of the library are formatted differently

Comment: On most configurations, the linker(!) will search for a library `libname.so` first failing that for a library `libname.a` but only in the configured library directories and that does not typically include the current directlory. Hence `-Ldir` is required for libraries that are outside this path. `-static` should not be required, here. `-static` *forces* static linking, but the linker will usually fall back to static linking automatically,  if a dynamic library isn't found.

Comment: @GreySage *Now it says my liblbryTest,a file is in the wrong format.* <- How did you create that `.a`? `.a` static libraries are generated by `ar` and to make them useable they also need a symbol table (i.e. `ar rs liblbryTest,a objectfiles` does the job).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know why the .a file isn't accepted, but that's another problem/question.